# Magento 1.8 assign products to categories with CSV and without categoryID

Tags: database, magento, csv, categories, product

I use Magento 1.8 and want to use the export/ import functionality of magento and no third party module, plugin and no php, wsdl. I must use the Magento csv import/ export cause I want to handle all with an extern database.
So my problem is, how can I assign products to categories with the product import. The products only have the field "category_ids". But category ids are set by magento and it's impossible to map them with the extern database. I read something like "_category" -> "Default Category/Category" but that doesn't work. Is something changed in magento 1.8?

Hope somebody can help me.
Best!